# Automation script to dismiss a playing video

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

I'm writing an UI Automation script where it needs to dismiss a *MPMoviePlayerViewController* view. I tried logging it using logElementTree() but only the navigation bar, tool bar, buttons are getting logged. Any pointer???

-MANN

Comment: How do you want to dismiss that video playback screen? Isn't the "done" button something you would want to use for that purpose?

Comment: Yes, But after some time (say in 5-10 seconds) done button disappears.

Comment: It appears again if you touch the screen again - so use the tap in conjunction with a coordinate as supported by UIAutomation.

Comment: I tried that but don't know why automation script consume some time after tapping. Navbar with 'Done' button appears but it again disappear till the time script tries to tap that'NavBar.leftButton().tap();'

Comment: no worries... using an alternative path now.

Comment: So what was your solution?